# Speaker - Electrical Characteristics

Tags: input-impedance

I have an inexpensive 2 inch diameter speaker.  The back is stamped with “8 ohm, 0.5 W”.  The measured DC resistance is 7.2 ohms.

Does the stamped “8 ohm” refer to the total impedance at some standard sine wave frequency, e.g., 1 kHz?  If so, does that mean that when driven at 1 kHz that the total impedance may be expressed as 7.2 + j0.8 ohms?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably \$7.2+j3.5\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the stamped “8 ohm” refer to the total impedance at some standard sine wave frequency, e.g., 1 kHz?

Only approximately. It's a "nominal" value, but the actual value can vary over a rather large range.

> If so, does that mean that when driven at 1 kHz that the total impedance may be expressed as 7.2 + j0.8 ohms?

No, impedances don't add that way, because of the phase angles involved.

If we assume that the speaker's impedance at 1000 Hz is exactly 8 Ω, then the reactive component is:

$$X = \sqrt{8\Omega^2 - 7.2\Omega^2} = 3.5\Omega$$

Comment: Do speakers really have such a high inductance?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Yes. They are copper coils with iron cores. However, the *mechanical* load of the cone effectively puts a relatively low resistance in parallel with the inductance.

Answer (score 0):

Just using this as an opportunity to reflect on why those impedances might be "nominal".

The speaker is an electro-mechanical-acoustical device and as such all those characteristics are seen across the two terminals on the back of the speaker.

Electrically there is the obvious resistance of the coils, the magnetic material interacting with the inductance as well as stray capacitance across coils of the inductor.

But wait, it gets more complicated.  The mechanical suspension system of the speaker also stores energy in deflections, it has dampening effects and when driven hard turns non-linear.  All of these effects are seen back at those same two terminals.

But wait, it gets even more complicated. The acoustical environment also effect how energy flows, resonance is one effect sometimes this effect is exploited deliberately  (the box the speakers are in) and sometimes it gets in the way and is not deliberate ( the actual room that the speakers are in - *most* people can't change that).  These interactions can have long delays, store energy as well and (here my memory is foggy, it has been a while) are represented by some complex partial differential equations whose solutions are Bessel functions.

Do you doubt this? Just think about how a speaker can also be used as a microphone.  That probably is enough of a proof.

As the frequency gets higher and the coupling of the speaker movement to the sound levels improves the departure from the ideal lessens. Tweeters are more ideal that woofers. Woofers have further departures from 8 Ohm (or 4 Ohm) nominal values than tweeters.

Answer (score 0):

Remember a loudspeaker is a form of electric motor, and therefore also a generator (microphone).

Therefore the DC resistance is analagous to the winding resistance of a motor and thus determines the resistance you would measure if the cone was locked solid and unable to move.

However the cone's movement allows the voice coil to act as a generator, generating "back EMF" (as in a motor), reducing the drive current, i.e. increasing the impedance.

Unlike a motor the back-EMF is quite small, (here, 10% of the drive voltage) reflecting the relatively low efficiency of the speaker (relatively little motion per applied volt).

At the loudspeaker's mechanical resonance, the cone's movement increases enormously, increasing the back-EMF, and that is reflected in a peak in the speaker's impedance at its resonant frequency - "8 ohm" LF drive units in Hi-Fi and PA systems may increase their impedance to 30 ohms or more at their resonant frequency.